# Chrome built-in picker for input type="time" chokes on input after min/max attribute change

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I found a rather annoying bug in Chrome built-in time picker related with updating the `min`/`max` attribute of `<input type="time">` on `change`, which I need.

Once the field contains a valid time the `change` event fires at each keystroke and changes `min`/`max` attribute. So, if I try to type a double digit in either hours or minutes Chrome will do funny things after the first keystroke. Let's say I have `01:00 PM` in the field and I focus on `00` and try to type different things:

```
  input    value transitions
 -------  --------------------------------------------
 1 1   :  01:00 PM => 01:01 PM => 01:01 PM
 1 0   :  01:00 PM => 01:01 PM => 01:00 PM
 1 1 1 :  01:00 PM => 01:01 PM => 01:01 PM => 01:11 PM
```

To me it looks like a bug in Chrome, but in the meantime I need some workaround (other than disabling the built-in picker) and I'm out of ideas. I've been able to isolate the issue so you can see it by yourself here:

https://jsfiddle.net/omegak/snoykv1j/

Answer (score 0):

We can workaround the issue by setting `max` attribute only if you need to change the max value.

```
if ($(e.target).attr('max'))
    $(e.target).attr('max', '');
```